# Fastlane Scan - default output directory on macOS

Tags: fastlane

What is the default `output_directory` for the [fastlane scan](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/scan/)?
Fastlane documentation tells that the exact value depends on the user's system, how can I get to know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most probably a subfolder `test_output` in the folder where you "enabled fastlane". So `./test_output` from where you are running `fastlane scan` is probably a good guess, if you are running it via a lane in a `Fastfile` then probably `./fastlane/test_output`.

---

Here is the code responsible for that:

```
containing = FastlaneCore::Helper.fastlane_enabled_folder_path
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/3fe3a7e91527f79512bf095519604a1132bd88b3/scan/lib/scan/options.rb#L14

```
default_value: File.join(containing, "test_output"),
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/3fe3a7e91527f79512bf095519604a1132bd88b3/scan/lib/scan/options.rb#L169

If you want to know the details how the folder path is retrieved, you can start at the helper method: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/2545fd0225b85c1204b30061f01a30ebd21d45d3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/helper.rb#L21-L23